# appending a semicolon to end of a line

Tags: python

I was intersted to know if there is a easy way to append a semicolon to the end of each line. I tried but always it prints the semicolon in the next line.

**rom_data.txt**

```
0123
1
253
3
```

**my_script.py**

```
input_file = open("rom_data.txt", "r")

for line in input_file:
    final= line+';'
    print final
```

**expected output**

```
0123;
1;
253;
3;
```

**output obtained**

```
0123 
;
1
;
253
;
3
;
```

Could anybody tell me where am i going wrong

Comment: It looks like you're maybe printing the lines (which include newlines at the ends) and tacking a semicolon onto that, so you're getting: `{content} \n ;`. You should consider stripping whitespace off the ends of the lines.

Comment: Ahh, welcome to the world of non-printing characters (line endings, among other things).  Trailing `\r\n` in your string?  Try printing `len(line)`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline : "A trailing newline character is kept in the string."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so your text file consists of lines. if you ask a viewer to show non-printable characters, it will show something like

```
0123\n
1\n
253\n
3\n
```

(or some other symbol marking the line break)

```
for line in input_file:  # so here "line" is "0123\n"
    final= line+';'      # here you append a semicolon, so it becomes "0123\n;"
    print final          # print adds another line break, so the output is "0123\n;\n"
```

a common solution would be to strip the line breaks first thing in the loop:

```
for line in input_file:
    line = line.strip() # here
    final= line+';'
    print final
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @Pavel points out the problem, but notice that there may be some problem.

That if you initial rom_data row begins or ends with some blank character, the strip() function will remove them all, which may not as expected.

For example:

**rom_data.txt:**

```
  0123  \n
123  \n
  456\n
```

may obtain output below:

```
0123\n
123\n
456\n
```

If you want to keep the blanks, you should only strip the last character:

```
for line in input_file:
    print(line[:-1]) # use this way to strip only the '\n' character at last
```

This may be more exact.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a newline character present in line. You will need to strip the newline character using rstrip. Refer below code:

```
input_file = open("rom_data.txt", "r")

for line in input_file:
    final= line.rstrip('\n') + ';'
    print final
```